# Normal distribution prior and posterior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, prior

Consider a razor company that is testing a new men's facial razor before releasing it for sale. They want it to have a certain performance rating (out of 100) before releasing it. Based on previous trials, the company has an approximately normal $N(70, 49)$ prior distribution of the razor's true performance rating. Now, the company is running a trial that they consider error-prone and will measure the razor's true performance (i.e. the rating from this trial can be modeled as approximately normal $N(x, 25)$. If this trial results in a rating of 85, what is the probability that the razor's true performance rates above 80?

---

I'm not quite sure how to begin with this problem. I think I need to use Bayesian inference and the formula for normal probability densities, but I don't know how to proceed. I think the $x$ in $N(x,25)$ is throwing me off the most––am I supposed to use 85 for that or should I just leave it as $x$ when I'm solving the problem? Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think $x$ denotes the unknown true rating, while $85$ is the observation from the Normal $\mathrm{N}(x,25)$.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you. So, would I have:

$f(\theta | X = 85) \propto f(85|\theta)f(\theta)$

$\propto \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{50\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{50}} \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{98\pi}} e^{\frac{-(x-70)^2}{98}}$ ?

Comment: Almost correct: (i) there is no $\mu$ in the first Normal pdf, use $(85-x)^2$ instead; (ii) $\theta$ on the lhs of $\propto$ needs to be rewritten as $x$, this is the unknown parameter!

Comment: @Xi'an Okay, thank you! So to solve this problem, I would integrate the function on the right-hand side––without the constants––from 85 to infinity, correct? Is there supposed to be a constant I add back in before I integrate?

Comment: Yes you have to integrate and yes you need the normalising constant, which is the (inverse of the) integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.